# VBA Code Adjustment - Loop, copy to new sheet

Tags: arrays, loops, excel, vba

I have the below code from Chandoo for excel. In the 'Data Sheet' it selects the sheet to copy to according to col. C, then copies col. A - G to that spreadsheet and moves to the next entry.

I am having trouble adjusting this code to suit my spreadsheet and would appreciate some assistance. My sheet name is in col. A (not c), and I only require col. B & C to be copied to the sheet. Additionally col. B & C need to be copied into col. B & G in the spreadsheet.

```
Sub copyPasteData()
    Dim strSourceSheet As String
    Dim strDestinationSheet As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    strSourceSheet = "Data entry"

    Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
    Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select

    Range("C2").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True
        Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
        lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")
        Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function LastRowInOneColumn(col)
    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    'http://www.rondebruin.nl/last.htm
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    LastRowInOneColumn = lastRow
End Function
```

Any assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a leason on the dangers of copying random code form the internet.  Manipulating the active selection like this is slow, hard to read, and hard to maintain.

Here's the code refactored to do this task in a more controlled fasion.

The origonal code (refactored) is included, commented out.  The code modified to reference your requested cells follows each original line

```
Sub copyPasteData()
    Dim strSourceSheet As String
    Dim strDestinationSheet As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rWs As Range
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDst As Range, cl As Range

    strSourceSheet = "Data entry"
    ' Get a reference to the source sheet
    Set wsSource = Worksheets(strSourceSheet)

    With wsSource
        ' Get a reference to the list of sheet names
        'Set rWs = Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))  ' for Column C
        Set rWs = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))  ' for Column A

        ' Loop through the sheet names list
        For Each cl In rWs.Cells
            ' Get a reference to the current row of data, all cells on that row
            'Set rSrc = cl.EntireRow.Resize(1, .Cells(cl.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
            Set rSrc = cl.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, 2)  ' Reference columns B and C only

            ' Get a reference to the current Destination sheet
            Set wsDest = Worksheets(cl.Value)
            With wsDest
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row  ' Check last row in Column B
                ' Copy data to destination using Value array
                '.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Resize(1, rSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rSrc.Value  ' all data
                .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = rSrc.Cells(1, 1) ' copy first cell to column B
                .Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = rSrc.Cells(1, 2) ' copy second cell to column G
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply.  Your suggested solution works perfectly for my needs.  Not too sure if this is possible, or if you have any further suggestions, but I require everything copied to col. B & G in the individual sheets to be replicated starting from row 25 in col B & G.

Would it be possible to use this code to replicate the outcome starting from row B25?

Thank you